# Is there an (11,3,3)-BIBD with specific conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Does there exist an $(11,3,3)-BIBD$ such that:

No element of $B$ is repeated where $B$ is the set of blocks.

There exists a subset $B'$ of $B$ such that any pair of elements of $\{1,2,...,11\}$ is in exactly 2 blocks of $B'$.

My thoughts on this are no. But it seems too easy. We know that in order for this design to exist there needs to be an $(11,3,2)-BIBD$ since $B'$ is just a subset of $B$. But we know by the well-known theorems that $r=10$ which implies $b\not \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is this right? Am I missing anything?

Comment: OK, now I agree that your proof is correct.